# Using LIKE with IN in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I want to use something like:

```
SELECT A.* FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE A, MYSCHEMA.SECONDTAB B WHERE A.COL1 LIKE B.COL1 || '%'
```

How to achieve this in DB2 ?

[Similar question but without an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838919/how-to-use-like-with-in-in-db2)

Comment: Please always explicitly qualify your joins, don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause).  For one thing, it makes finding the correlation conditions much easier for humans (and doesn't really affect computers).  It also makes dealing with `LEFT JOIN`s easier.

Comment: I see 3 answers in that question. And your code has no `IN`. Why did put it in the title?

Comment: What is the data type of column COL1 in each of the two tables involved?

Comment: @FredSobotka: Varchar is the datatype for all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so sure what you try to achieve but it works in DB2. Just add TRIM function at `LIKE TRIM(B.COL1) || '%'`  or swap it to `WHERE B.COL1 LIKE TRIM(A.COL1) || '%'`

[edit]
Above works in DB2 in as/400(or whatever name they call it right now)

Below might work with DB2 LUW (tested with DB2 windows v8.2), assuming COL1 type = varchar

```
WHERE SUBSTR(A.COL1,1,LENGTH(A.COL1)) = SUBSTR( B.COL1, 1,LENGTH(A.COL1))
```

Comment: Not working! Getting error Message: A LIKE predicate or POSSTR scalar function is not valid because the first operand is not a string expression or the second operand is not a string.  A LOCATE or POSITION scalar function is not valid because the first operand is not a string or the second operand is not a string expression.

Comment: @Nikunj Chauhan, Please look at updated answer. Sorry, initially i just test with DB2 in as/400 and thought it works with other DB2 flavour. Probably others have better/easier answer

Comment: Both queries work on DB2 LUW v9.7. 

In the second query, the first SUBSTR expression is kind of pointless because SUBSTR of A.COL1 from 1 to the length of A.COL1 is an expensive way of saying A.COL1

Comment: @Fred Sobotka. you are right, the first SUBSTR is useless and thanks for checking on v9.7.