# DB2 efficient select query with like operator for many values (~200)

Tags: sql, db2

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT TBSPACE FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TYPE='T' AND (TABNAME LIKE '%_ABS_%' OR TABNAME LIKE '%_ACCT_%')
```

This gives me a certain amount of results. Now the problem is that I have multiple `TABNAME` to select using the `LIKE` operator (~200). **Is there an efficient way to write the query for the 200 values without repeating the `TABNAME LIKE` part** (because there are 200 such values which would result in a really huge query) ?

(If it helps, I have stored all required `TABNAME` values in a table `TS` to retrieve from)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use LIKE with IN in DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838919/how-to-use-like-with-in-in-db2)

Comment: Hi @vahdet, I am less interested in using the `LIKE OR` part because there are 200 such values. This is why I want to know whether there is another way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for substrings, you could use `LOCATE`. E.g.

```
WITH SS(S) AS (
    VALUES
        ('_ABS_')
    ,   ('_ACCT_')
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABNAME
FROM
    SYSCAT.TABLES, SS
WHERE
    TYPE='T' 
AND LOCATE(S,TABNAME) > 0
```

or if your substrings are in table `CREATE TABLE TS(S VARCHAR(64))`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABNAME
FROM
    SYSCAT.TABLES, TS
WHERE
    TYPE='T' 
AND LOCATE(S,TABNAME) > 0
```

Comment: The problem is, like ABS, ACCT, there are 200 such values

Comment: Cant it be possible that these values be retrieved from a table (I have stored it in a table) and then substituted in the `VALUES` ?

Comment: sure, just replace my SS with your table

Answer (score 0):

You could try `REGEXP_LIKE`. E.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABNAME
FROM
    SYSCAT.TABLES
WHERE
    TYPE='T' 
AND REGEXP_LIKE(TABNAME,'.*_((ABS)|(ACCT))_.*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case.
Note, that the '_' character has special meaning in a `pattern-expression` of the [LIKE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000751.html) predicate:

> - The underscore character (_) represents any single character.
> - The percent sign (%) represents a string of zero or more characters.
> - Any other character represents itself.

So, if you really need to find `_ABS_` substring, you should use something like below.
You get both rows in the result, if you use the commented out pattern instead, which may not be desired.

```
with 
  pattern (str) as (values
  '%\_ABS\_%'
--'%_ABS_%'
)
, tables (tabname) as (values
  'A*ABS*A'
, 'A_ABS_A'
)
select tabname
from tables t
where exists (
  select 1
  from pattern p
  where t.tabname like p.str escape '\'
);
```